# Touch/Tap vs href for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, web, href

I am developing a mobile website. I am using a lot of links (`href`).  I want to know whether I should give normal `href` link or should I use some javascript to detect touch and direct to that `href` value. Which one will be faster and more user friendly ? I am using hammer.js for touch events. Can some help me to figure it out ?